# Axis2 version 1.8.2 soap envelope missing in request

Tags: apache-axis

We are upgrading from Axis2 1.5.1 to 1.8.2 and after using WSDL2JAVA to regenerate the code and making the minor import changes we have successfully compiled and ran the system.
However it failed in testing when testing SOAP calls. Our test harness expects the SOAP request to contain the soap envelope but it does not anymore.

While we are expecting the request to start as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:GetOurData xmlns:ns1="http://example.org/company/data/v1_5">
```

It actually starts with:

```
        <ns1:GetOurData xmlns:ns1="http://example.org/company/data/v1_5">
```

We have been debugging and googling for solutions, most are referring to outdated APIs in order to add the envelope into the service client which I think should already be there.

Our code to generate the sub is very simple:

```
stub = new ServiceStub(url);
Options options = stub._getServiceClient().getOptions();
options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.SO_TIMEOUT, fiveMin);
options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, fiveMin);
options.setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(fiveMin);
```

Has anyone experienced this or has a solution?

Thanks in advance
Jay